# Isentropic and Isothermal Compressibility

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Why isentropic compressibility is greater than isothermal compressibility ?

While deriving $C_p$ and $C_v$ relation, I got $\frac{Cp}{Cv}$ as $\frac{ke}{Kt}$.

Which tells us that $Ke > Kt$. But why is it so?

Is it always $ke > Kt$ or are there any exceptions?

Comment: We can't read your mind. Show your derivation!

Comment: Same derivation is in wikipedia. (Ratio b/w Cp and Cv).     
                                                                                                                                      http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities                                                                                                                                                           Since  Cp > Cv, which implies that Ke > Kt. Plz Give me reasons why Ke should be greater Kt.

Comment: The wikipedia article defines their terms. You did not.

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake. Ke is the isentropic compressibility and Kt is the isothermal compressibility .  Kt= change in volume of a system as the pressure changes at constant temperature . Isothermal compressibility is derived from the slopes of P-V diagram. And isentropic compressibility is the change in volume of a system as the pressure changes at constant  entropy. Cp and Cv are the specific heats at constant pressure and volume respectively.

Comment: In
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio#Real_gas_relations
you"ll find a good explamation.